# Makefile "re-read" question

Tags: file, makefile

So I am building a makefile system very similar to the linux kernel Kconfig work.

That is the user would type "make menuconfig" and it creates a menu driven mechanism for turning build modules on/off.  Pretty easy being that I stole most of it from Linux and open source.

The only problem I have is re-reading the newly created .config file.

So what happens is that "make menuconfig" does the following:

> .PHONY: menuconfig
>   menuconfig: ${SCRIPTS_DIR}/config/mconf check_config ${TOP}/gnet.kconfig
>       @${SCRIPTS_DIR}/config/mconf gnet.kconfig

The ${SCRIPTS_DIR}/config/mconf uses the gnet.kconfig as a starter config and then creates a .config file in the ${TOP} directory.

What I want to do is have the .config re-evaluated so I can get some parameters out of it and know if the user changed anything significant.

I've tried the following without much luck.

> .config: menuconfig
>       cp .config default-config/arm-config

Something like that.. but the .config is the old one, not the new one.

I hope I explained this well enough.

Thanks.
-stv

Comment: This should work; I suspect you're leaving something out. What version of Make are you using, and what output does it produce?

Answer (score 1):

As Beta noted, you've left out some relevant things. How is the target `.config` related to `menuconfig`? Are the two even related at all? Are you sure the second recipe gets executed?
When you run `make menuconfig`, the target `menuconfig` becomes the ultimate goal that make will try to update. Since it is a PHONY target, its recipe will always be executed. Before it does that, make checks if its dependencies exist and are up to date. As I said, you don't show a link between the targets `menuconfig` and `.config`, so what would cause the recipe for `.config` to be executed?

On a related issue, your rules are not telling the truth to make. Your first rule shown creates the file `.config`, so that should be in the list of targets for that rule. Your second rule depends on the existence of that file, so it should be among the dependencies here, and then creates a file `default-config/arm-config`, which should thus be the target of this rule.

```
.PHONY: menuconfig
menuconfig .config: ${SCRIPTS_DIR}/config/mconf check_config ${TOP}/gnet.kconfig
      @${SCRIPTS_DIR}/config/mconf gnet.kconfig
```

```
default-config/arm-config: .config
      cp .config default-config/arm-config
```

Comment: I think Steve is running `make .config`.

Comment: Possibly. The second part of my answer still remains valid in that case (unless I misunderstood what he's doing, of course).

Comment: I added as answer answer to my question because it was too long.  :)

Comment: fantastic.. they keep deleting my replies.. guess I'm not concise or good enough.. I'll figure it out.. thanks for the replies Beta and eriktous